# Alarm manager do not dismiss after notification click

Tags: android, notifications, alarmmanager

I have been trought all the alarm manager codes but i dont manage to see where my error is

What i want to archieve is this, when i open the app it executes the code in the main and set the alarm manager timer to pop up a notification, but when i close the app and wait for the popup to appear is not showing , but when i start again the app the notification appears

When i click the notification in the task bar it dosnt disapear it sends me to my main activity, thats ok but the notification in the task bar does not destroy :(

here is my code

```
 import android.app.AlarmManager;
import android.app.PendingIntent;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton;
import android.support.design.widget.Snackbar;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;

import java.util.Calendar;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);




        Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();

        calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY,1);
        calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE,12);
        calendar.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);

        Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),Notification_reciever.class);

        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(getApplicationContext(), 100, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

        AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
        alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,calendar.getTimeInMillis(),AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY,pendingIntent);




    }

}
```

and here it is my notification reciever

```
import android.app.NotificationManager;
import android.app.PendingIntent;
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v4.app.NotificationCompat;

/**
 * Created by Usuario on 01/05/2016.
 */
public class Notification_reciever extends BroadcastReceiver {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

        Intent repeating_intent = new Intent(context,MainActivity.class);
        repeating_intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);

        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context,100,repeating_intent,PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

        NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context)
                .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
                .setSmallIcon(android.R.drawable.arrow_up_float)
                .setContentTitle("GIOTON")
                .setContentText("Prueba de notificaciones")
                .setAutoCancel(true);

        notificationManager.notify(100,builder.build());



    }
}
```

Comment: its kinda like , when i have the app in second plane executing in background the notification appears at the time i set it up, but when i close the app entirely i dont see the notification , so i need to have the app opened and runing in background , and i want the notification to show when the app is entirely closed or not even open

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use Broadcast Receiver to dismiss the notification by Id.

Intent startIntent = new Intent( context,
                    NotificationClickReciever.class );
use notification click receiver while creating intent.

Below code to dismiss notification -

public static void cancelNotification( Context ctx, int notifyId ) {

```
    String s = Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE;

    NotificationManager mNM = ( NotificationManager ) ctx.getSystemService( s );
    mNM.cancel( notifyId );
enter code here
}
```